# I'm not getting back number in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a code like this:

```
type State = {
  ...
  PromotionIDs: Number[];
  autoAdjustUsage: AutoAdjustUsage[]
};

const InitState: State = {
  ...
  PromotionIDs: [],
  autoAdjustUsage: []
};


    const contracts = this.state[PointsTableType.ELIGIBLE].contracts;
    let result = this.state.PromotionIDs.map(i=>Number(i));
    const autoAdjustPayload = {
      promotionIDs: result,
      usageYears: contracts.map(x => ({ usageYearId: x.usageId, applied: x.appliedPoints,usageType:x.usageType }))
    };

    console.log("this.state.PromotionIDs: ", this.state.PromotionIDs)
```

I'm not getting back any number when I console.log PromotionID. Does anyone know how can I fix this?

Comment: Nothing is being added to state.promotionIDs in this code. Why would you expect the array to be populated?

Comment: You have to set state, map create new array not mutated the current array, you should do the following:  this.setState({ PromotionIDs: result })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have that value in state you have to update the state.

Something like this should work.

```js
...
let result = this.state.PromotionIDs.map(i=>Number(i));
this.setState({ PromotionIDs: result });
...
```